# How to refer data to different sheets (with different range cells in the main sheet)

Tags: excel, vba

I am building an excel sheet, in which it copy the data with reference cells in other sheet in the same excel I have this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b10:B10")) Is Nothing Then

        If IsNumeric(Target) Then

            'Stop any possible runtime errors and halting code

            On Error Resume Next

                'Turn off ALL events so the Target does not put the code into a loop.

                Application.EnableEvents = False

                Call Update_Monthly

                'Turn events back on

                Application.EnableEvents = True

            'Allow run time errors again

            On Error GoTo 0

        End If

    End If



End Sub
```

And I made another code in the module of WS2 with this code:

```
Sub Update_Monthly()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Daily Testing")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Monthly Record")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lr = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To 5
ws2.Cells(i + lr, "C") = ws1.Cells(i + 5, "B")
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The coloumn range refer data to sheet 2
Now if I have sheet3 , sheet 4
How will I refer data with same code w1 ( but differes only in Range b10:B10)?